# How to install IronPython in ArchLinux?

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation, python

I would like to install IronPython2.7 for ArchLinux. I've already installed mono and extracted a [file](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython2/releases/tag/ipy-2.7.11) containing the source, a solution file and others but I cannot find any instructions on how to install it.

If anyone knows the steps it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython2 contains a link to https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython2/blob/master/Documentation/building.md - s that not good enough?

Answer (score 1):

Well, hopefully you know about the Arch User Repositories ([AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/));
it's in there!
https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ironpython/

Fire up your preferred AUR manager tool (mine is [trizen](https://wiki.archlinux.de/title/Trizen) by the way, the syntax is 99,99% like pacman), and install  it.

In general in Arch, try to do everything within the package management! Then you never will have any trouble and installations which serve you a decade or more.

PS: packages which are seldom used sometimes do not compile/install (upstream bug or dependency broken). In those cases, please report a bug. In most cases, maintainers help at some point. Be patient -- people are doing that in their free time and sometimes miss the point that other people use that stuff for business :-)

PPS: also try to avoid things like python's pip, if an alternative is available in the Arch repositories.